# Autocompletion in TypeScript objects and their definitions

Tags: typescript, autocomplete

Shouldn't these be the same?

```
const greeting = {
  hello: "Hello",
  hi: "Hi"
}

greeting. // this will give autocompletion as expected.


greeting.hey = 'Hey'

greeting. // the `hey` won't show up in the autocompletion.
```

Why is that, is there any work around?

I'm using types, but I didn't know what types I should define in this case.

Comment: The compiler won't let you assign to `greeting.hey`, because that's not part of the inferred type: https://tsplay.dev/Wol99w.

Comment: do you think if there is any work around?

Comment: There are several options, but which one's going to be appropriate depends on your context. Maybe it should be an optional property, so it doesn't need to be defined initially, or perhaps you should use an index signature so any key is valid. Read e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html.

Comment: let me read it, I will get back to you once I'm done

Comment: well, it appears that there is no such way of extending typesc after declaration on the fly, I thought of `process.env` I looked up many solutions for that but all are extending the same same global node object, and I've tried my self few other solutions but it seems to be a waste of time, thanks for the answer and the question edit though 